Valgrind shows weird results when using it with SDL2
I am writing an additional layer on SDL2 for personal use. I'd like to check for memory leaks, so I downloaded Valgrind and read a quick start page.
I launched a program that uses my library in Valgrind, and a gigantic flow of errors got printed in my terminal. This confused me, so I coded the most simple SDL2 program I could imagine, and launched it in Valgrind. The result is quite confusing.
My program (main.c):
int main(void){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("sxdfcgvh", 0, 0, 720, 480, 0);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_Rect rect = {1, 1, 100, 100};
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    while (event.type != SDL_KEYDOWN){
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer, &rect);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

Compiling and launching command :
gcc main.c -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -O3 -o xyz.out && valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./xyz.out

Valgrind output :
==30540== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30540==     in use at exit: 335,611 bytes in 3,360 blocks
==30540==   total heap usage: 81,476 allocs, 78,116 frees, 23,727,953 bytes allocated
==30540== 
==30540== 6,592 (232 direct, 6,360 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,407 of 2,413
==30540==    at 0x484D953: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30540==    by 0x52E7232: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.32.4)
==30540==    by 0x52EF587: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.32.4)
==30540==    by 0x52F189D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.32.4)
==30540==    by 0x52E1872: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.32.4)
==30540==    by 0x52CD28D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.32.4)
==30540==    by 0x52CE6F0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.32.4)
==30540==    by 0x4996B13: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==30540==    by 0x48A337E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.3000.0)
==30540==    by 0x1091EC: main (in /home/pierre/Desktop/Hobbes/programs/C/SDLLearn/xyz.out)
==30540== 
==30540== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30540==    definitely lost: 232 bytes in 1 blocks
==30540==    indirectly lost: 6,360 bytes in 35 blocks
==30540==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30540==    still reachable: 329,019 bytes in 3,324 blocks
==30540==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30540== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==30540== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==30540== 
==30540== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==30540== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

It looks like even a simple SDL2 program has memory leaks. Is this normal ? If so, how do I know whether my library's memory leaks come from my code or from SDL2 ?
Edit : When adding -g in the compiling command, Valgrind tells me that the command that allocates this memory is SDL_Init() (which is weird, because I get no leak when launching a code with only SDL_Init() and SDL_Quit())
Note : It looks like the leak comes from drawing functions, because Valgrind shows no leak when I remove SDL_RenderDrawRect() and SDL_RenderPresent()

Add -g in your compiler command to have the filename and line numbers in valgrind. Then you see which command allocates the memory.

I just did it and edited the post :) as you can see, it's even more confusing to me...

Authors of poor quality tools and libraries are often too lazy to deallocate all resources, saying that it doesn’t matter and the OS will reclaim the resources. Do they at least provide a suppression file? In order to analyze the leaks you will need either a debuginfo package (if your district/OS has them) or else build SDL2 from source with debug info.

... and enable debug symbols on libdbus, too.

If the above trace is with -g then you need to modify the build instructions, too.  I usually do -g3, btw, to have the most information available.

@AllanWind I don't know much about compiling options or symbols, I'll try to learn a little more and then I'll apply your advice :)

@PaulFloyd I'm quite surprised, deallocating the ressources looks like the most basic thing to do in a clean code to me... I don't know much about suppression files or debuginfo packages, so I think I'll rather compile the source with debug info.
Also, in that case, how should I know whether the leaks in my library come from my code or from SDL2 ?

@Hobbes you need to look at the call stack. However that won’t tell you if there is a way to instigate cleanup.
